# What does crook's fluctuation theorem exactly say?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium

As far as I understand, entropy production fluctuation theorems such as crook's fluctuation theorem give an expression for ratio of probabilities of happening of forward event to backward event depending on the entropy generated. So, it appears to me that they point out time symmetry breaking as one direction is more preferred. But then, they are fundamentally derived from stochastic microscopically reversible dynamics. Can reversibility at micro scale give rise to irreversibility at macro-scale? What am I missing?

Comment: The answer to this question depends heavily on your definition of "irreversibility". Is an event that has a very high forward probability and a very low reverse probability considered irreversible?

Comment: Yes, according to my understanding.

Comment: For one thing you are missing that in reality all systems are either open or in thermal equilibrium with the remainder of the universe. In a relativistic universe open systems are always irreversible. (Infrared) electromagnetic radiation never returns to its emitter. In thermal equilibrium the thermal bath takes care of the irreversibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as a kind of regression to the mean.

The space of possible configurations of many-particle systems is very large. By definition, low-entropy macrostates of these systems occupy a very small region of this configuration space, and high-entropy macrostates occupy almost all of the configuration space. The system has the same probability of being at any point in configuration space (this is taken as an assumption). Therefore, if you start out in a small area in configuration space, the probability of you *remaining* in that area of configuration space after randomly adopting another configuration is very small.

Repeated outliers are rare (that's why they're outliers in the first place), so if the system is currently an outlier, it's unlikely to remain one.

Comment: I agree with you, but I have a followup question/thought. Why do you assume, that the next configuration is random?

Comment: @Kregnach Because we can't calculate "the next configuration", not even for fairly simple systems like a three body problem. The ergodic hypothesis is known to be false (we can give trivial counterexamples), but it's a good rule of thumb that gives "correct" results for many systems. You can, if you want, divide the world into systems that are "sufficiently ergodic" and "the rest", if you like. The former can be treated with a fairly straight forward theory and the latter can, if I am not mistaken. not be easily characterized.